# Pseudorandom functions in ACC^0?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, cr.crypto-security, circuit-complexity, natural-proofs

In the lower bound result by Ryan Williams (Non-uniform $\mathsf{ACC}$ circuit lower bounds), there is a mention of "little evidence that Pseudorandom function generators exist in $\mathsf{ACC}^0$. Is there any development in this regard that might be of interest? (Even old results implying something along these lines will be great.)

Comment: The following paper doesn't answer your question but does show somewhat simpler candidate PRFs http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/papers/spn.pdf